# Comments for each image in a gallery

Tags: 7, comments, media

I'm trying to setup a gallery where users can comment under each image. What is the best way to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple setup:

You need two content types:

- Gallery
- Image

The gallery content type will contain a body (gallery description) field.

The image content type will contain:

- Image field
- A [reference](http://drupal.org/project/references) field

The reference field will reference a gallery content type.

Comment: also https://drupal.org/project/bulk_file_nodes module is useful to upload or import many files at once, and have many individual nodes created, one for each file.