# How to add comments per picture in a photo album?

Tags: comments, media

I have an activities content type that I want to add a photo gallery to (in the same content type). However I want comment capabilities per picture. How can I achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comments for each image in a gallery](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/57073/comments-for-each-image-in-a-gallery)

Comment: Create a new content type, and I guess you would have to do a node per each image.

Answer (score 0):

Would build this by creating a single content type with only one picture per node with the comments turned on just as you did.  Then build a view for your gallery with the comment as a link included.